# How to bind to JSON and populate Kendo DropDownLists

Tags: javascript, json, rest, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm having trouble with returning valid data with the following JSON. When I bind I'm getting back 'undefined' likely due to the format. I need to bind two DDL's to the following data. One binds to StreetsInTown and the other StreetNumsOnStreet:

```
{
    "StreetsInTown": "[{\"Street\":\"AARON RD\"},{\"Street\":\"ACCESS RD\"},,{\"Street\":\"WILSON ST\"},{\"Street\":\"WINDSOR ST\"},{\"Street\":\"WOOD TER\"},{\"Street\":\"WOODLAND AVE\"},{\"Street\":\"ZOLAN DR\"}]",
    "StreetNumsOnStreet": "[{\"Street_Num\":\"18\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"19\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"26\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"27\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"32\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"39\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"43\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"44\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"55\"},{\"Street_Num\":\"66\"}]"
}
```

The workflow:

1. User has selected Town with DDL1, result creates "StreetsInTown" string.
2. Populate DDL2 with "StreetsInTown" string.
3. Select a Street with DDL2, result creates "StreetNumsOnStreet" string.
4. Populate DDL3 with "StreetNumsOnStreet" string.

I have control over the creation of the JSON. So if a better format is suggested I can tweak the REST endpoint. Fyi, I'm using javascript, without a model. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe I need to do a  JSON.parse() to get the "StreetsInTown.Street" to populate DDL2, but not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use a primary key from your database to identify streets and street numbers?  I have some drop downs that cascade via ajax.  I serialize a C# IEnumerable and the data comes back like this:

> [{"Selected":false,"Text":"Mike
>   DAuria","Value":"4347"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Sean
>   Kelly","Value":"4348"}]

The Value is a PK from the database and the Text is the name I want to show in the dropdown.

Kendo lets you specify what properties you bind to.  In my case, I tell it "Text" is the text and "Value" is the value.

If you don't have/need a PK, try setting both to the same property.  {text="AARON RD"}  and in Kendo do dataTextField: "text", dataValueField: "text".

Comment: No, PK as I'm using data created by a SQL view. I did set the dataTextField and dataValueField to = "StreetsInTown.Street" as @OnaBai mentions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764314/proper-binding-of-json-to-kendo-dropdownlist/19765829#19765829) but still no luck.